# Join 3 JavaScript arrays by 2 keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, lodash

1.What is an effective way of joining these 3 arrays: (examples using lodash etc. are most welcome)

```
 [
    { id : "A", year : 1990, x : 10}
    { id : "B", year : 1990, x : 10}
 ]

 [
    { id : "A", year : 1990, y : 100}
    { id : "B", year : 1990, y : 100}
 ]

 [
    { id : "A", year : 1990, z : 1000}
    { id : "B", year : 2000, z : 1000}
 ]
```

To get this result:

```
[
   { id : "A", year : 1990, x : 10, y: 100, z: 1000}
   { id : "B", year : 1990, x : 10, y: 100, z: 1000}
   { id : "B", year : 2000, z : 1000}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a lodash solution.  It's essentially just a `groupBy` on `id` and `year`, and then a map that merges all of the matching objects together.

```
//assuming your three arrays are "a", "b", and "c"
_(a).concat(b).concat(c) //begin lodash chaining syntax, join arrays
    .groupBy(function(obj) { //group by the combination of the id and year
        return obj.id + "|" + obj.year;
    })
    .map(Function.apply.bind(_.merge, null)) //merge array of objects matching id and year into a single object
.value() //end lodash chaining syntax
```

Comment: what about changing the current map to `.map(Function.apply.bind(_.merge, null))`?

Comment: Good call; that's a bit cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Using a temporary object that has the concatenation of the 2 main keys as property names you can do something like:

```
var a= [
    { id : "A", year : 1990, x : 10},
    { id : "B", year : 1990, x : 10}
 ];

var b= [
    { id : "A", year : 1990, y : 100},
    { id : "B", year : 1990, y : 100}
 ];

 var c= [
    { id : "A", year : 1990, z : 1000},
    { id : "B", year : 2000, z : 1000}
 ];
 var tmp={},
     arrs=[a,b,c]


arrs.forEach(function( mainArr){     
     mainArr.forEach(function(obj){
         var combinedKeys= obj.id + obj.year;
         if(!tmp[combinedKeys]){
             tmp[combinedKeys] ={}  
         }
         var keys = Object.keys(obj)
         keys.forEach(function(key){
             if(!tmp[combinedKeys].hasOwnProperty(key)){
                 tmp[combinedKeys][key]=obj[key] ;
             }
         });
     });     
 });        

var newArr=[];
for( key in tmp){
    newArr.push(tmp[key]);
}
```

This will be non destructive and leave original arrays untouched

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b7400xkr/1)**</kbd>